# How can I run a script in maple?

Tags: maple

In every coding language there is some possibility to run a script; Like in Matlab I can run a simple script/function like:

```
 function [b] = test(a)

      for i=1:100 
           b(i)=a+i;
      end
 end
```

So if I type in test(20) I get a vector b=[21, 22, ..., 120]; Now I just started with maple and I'm pretty confused;
I get an empty sheet with the mode "2d Math" where I can type e.g. 5+2 and get the result 7;
However I am truly unable to create an easy function like the one shown above;
Does anyone have an idea how to do that?

Many thanks

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways to make what is called a *procedure* in Maple. The most general way is

```
test:= proc(a::algebraic)
local i;
     <seq(a+i, i= 1..100)>
end proc;
```

To use the procedure, do

```
b:= test(20);
```

The "2d math" style is hideous---rife with bugs. Before you get used it, I recommend switching to Maple Input (sometimes called 1D input). You can set this option permanently from the Tools->Options menu.

Answer (score 2):

You can read about programming in Maple, and authoring procedures, in the manuals.

The manuals are available to you directly in the Maple Help system, but the links I give below are to the [Online version](http://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/) of the Help system (latest version).

A quick start is the section [Basic Programming](http://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=UserManual%2FChapter09) in the [User Manual](http://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=UserManual%2FContents), and the subsection on [procedures](http://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=UserManual%2FChapter09#procedures).

For more advanced programming, look at the [Programming Guide](http://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=ProgrammingGuide/Contents), which also has a subsection on [procedures](http://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=ProgrammingGuide%2FChapter01#bookmark24).

These sections of the manuals also cover ways to share a defined procedure amongst various Maple sessions, as well as several ways (or locations) in which you can author them in the GUI (Graphical User Interface).

And of course the [proc](http://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=procedure) command also has its own detailed set of help pages.